# Dart Function returns null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a function which calls request to create a new Student in server

```
createStudents(String studentName) async {
await Webservice()
    .postReq(new API().createNewStudent(context), studentName)
    .then((value) {
  if (value is Students) {
    Students std = value;
    helper.initializeDatabase();
    helper.insertStudents(std);
    return "Sucessfull";
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});
```

}

in this example i sent name of student and new student is created in server.

if succesfull it returns a student object.

and if not succesfull then message is returned.

i debugged and checked value in this function but it always return null.

when sucessful it returns Student object but createStudents function returns null. same for error message

```
var ab = await createTags(data);
                  print(ab);
```

ab is always null.

i dont know why it always returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but my best guess is that you forgot "return" statement

```
createStudents(String studentName) async {
    //Here should be return
    final value = await Webservice()
        .postReq(new API().createNewStudent(context), studentName);
        
      if (value is Students) {
        Students std = value;
        helper.initializeDatabase();
        helper.insertStudents(std);
        return "Sucessfull";
      } else {
        return value;
      }
 }
```

Comment: sure, but the real question is why is he using both `then` and `await`? it could be simplified a lot by only using `await` stuff

Comment: exactly, this is what i meant

Comment: there is if else, so it should return either way.
i checked it returns but when i catch it , it gives null

Comment: @UmeshChakradhar no, you return a value from `then` callback, not from your function - check the answer how it should be done using only `await` stuff (and not a combination of `await` and `then`)

Comment: thank you @ArtemZelinskiy yes i got it now.

Comment: @pskink i am new to flutter and not so familiar with await , asynce etc.

Comment: @pskink why cant i use then and await both??any reason.?

Comment: @UmeshChakradhar you can but your code will be more complex and whats worse you can have more "stupid" bugs like you had in your question - at first everything looks ok (you return a value) but still `null` is returned

Comment: @pskink okay thank you, now last question, was previous unedited answer ok?? and if yes which one is more efficient ?? and why?? please reply polietly...

Comment: @UmeshChakradhar yes, it was ok, but now it is better since it is more simple and now it does not have any tricky parts where someone could fall into